# Objective C - Precompiled Headers Creating Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am importing some classes in **.pch** file it is working fine. I can build and run too but when those classes that are included in **.pch** file are accessed complier gives error but still it an build successfully and run the program too. But as soon as i again import them in some class then complier doesn't gives any error. What is the problem that is causing this?

**Edit:** I tried Cleaning Project and build folder but no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by quoting Xcode forcefully and by going to finder->Gotofolder

**~/library/developer/xcode/deriveddata**

and deleting everything and when i tried running again i was not prompted any error

Answer (score 0):

if you add the three lines under Search Paths->Framework Search Paths as mentioned below 
$(inherited)
$(SRCROOT)
"$(SRCROOT)/frameworkname"

I think the problem is Complier not able to locate the framework.
Hope this will help